# Create a bzr branch that selectively omits some commits from parent branch

Tags: bazaar

Is it possible to create a branch of a bzr repository that selects omits certain changes? For example, let's say my repository is at revision 354, and I want to branch it, but I don't want to include the changes that were done in revision 247.

Note that I plan to merge in the changes from revision 247 at some point in the future. So I don't want to just make changes to the code that undo what revision 247 did, otherwise there will be a conflict later when I try to do the merge.

Is this type of selective branching possible with bzr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to [Reverse Cherrypick](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/bzr.dev/en/user-guide/adv_merging.html#reverse-cherrypicking). This will let you remove a single revision from a branch.

Comment: Gavin, I don't know how [**your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928404/returning-a-flexible-datatype-from-a-c-function) got migrated here without associating to your account, unless you used a different OpenID over at programmers.stackexchange.com.  You might try associating your accounts between the two sites, but if that doesn't work, and you still feel strongly about it, you may need to email team@stackoverflow.com to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

no.
A revision always guarantees all of it's parent revisions.
I don't think you will have too many conflicts if you first undo and commit that revision and then later re-apply it.
If you are unsure branch into a temp directory and try it out.