# Returning a flexible datatype from a C++ function

Tags: c++

I'm developing for a legacy C++ application which uses ODBC for it's data access. Coming from a C# background, I really miss the ADO style of data access.

I'm writing a wrapper (because we can't actually use ADO) to make our data access less painful. This means no `char` arrays, no manual text blob streaming, and no declaritive column binding.

I'm struggling with how to store / return data values. In C# at least, you can declare an `object` and cast it to whatever (as long as the type is convertable).

My current C++ solution is to use `boost::any` to store the data value in a custom `DataColumnValue` object. This class has conversion and assignment operators to the various types used in our app (more than 10). There's a bit of complexity here because if you store an `int` in the `boost::any` and try to `boost::any_cast<long>` you get a `boost::bad_any_cast`. Client objects shouldn't have to know how the value is stored internally.

Does anyone have any experience trying to store / return values whose types are only known at runtime? Is there a better / cleaner way?

Comment: This looks like it would be better asked over at SO.

Comment: Can you please explain why? What is this site about if not programming related questions?

Comment: @Gavin: This site is about good subjective questions about programming. See the question section in the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq). Closing in migration to SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) (http://otl.sourceforge.net/) in some one-off projects back in the day for interfacing C++ and some SQL Server databases.  It's streams-based, so it can do type conversion for you.  I did find the streams paradigm a bit confusing at times, as I had to unstream the values in the query order - I never quite figured out how to pull a named value out of the record stream.

But it worked flawlessly otherwise.

---

In regards to Boost.Any, I've implemented similar constructs before, copying the COM Variant as a C++ union.  With Boost.Variant/Any you might need to add addition template specializations to support the particular datatype conversions you're attempting (long is not an int after all).  I don't see any particular downside to your approach except scalability in number of types.

Comment: OTL looks interesting, but I'm kind of trapped as far as database API goes. I'm more interested in the C++ approach to passing around data.